# Getting unwanted “Windows fatal exception” on running “pywinatuo” script on Lenovo laptop

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I don't know why the same script is running fine on one system and throwing lot of fatal exception on other models

**Environment**
**Python version**: 3.7.2 (tried with both 32 & 64 bit executable)
**Pywinauto**: 0.6.8
**Operating system**: Windows 10 (Build version: 16299)
**Laptop Model**: yoga

Also tried with installing python & pywinatuo as Administrative mode but still getting the same error message.

>
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
'''def test_powerpoint_perf_activity():
      os.startfile(testfilepath)
      connectApp=
      Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re='.*'+file_name+'*.')
      connectWindow = connectApp.window(title_re='.*'+file_name+'*.')

      if connectWindow.is_maximized() == False:
         connectWindow.MaximizeButton.click_input()

      connectWindow.HOMETabItem.click_input()
      connectWindow.NewSlideMenuItem.click_input()
      connectWindow.TitleandTextListItem.click_input()'''
```

> ### platform win32 -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-5.2.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
>
> ```
>   c:\python37_32\python.exe
> cachedir: .pytest_cache
> metadata: {'Python': '3.7.2', 'Platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0', 'Packages': {'pytest': '5.2.2', 'py':
> ```
>
> '1.8.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.0'}, 'Plugins': {'allure-pytest': '2.8.6',
>   'html': '2.0.0', 'metadata': '1.8.0'}}
>       rootdir: C:\securityapps_master_m\testcases                                                                                                               `enter code here`plugins: allure-pytest-2.8.6, html-2.0.0,
>   metadata-1.8.0
>       collecting ... ERROR: The process "POWERPNT.EXE" not found.
>       ERROR: The process "IEXPLORE.EXE" not found.
>       collected 1 item
>
> ```
> test_san_tool.py::test_TC02_Dictionary Windows fatal exception: code 0xe0000002
> Thread 0x00002ea0 (most recent call first):
>   File "C:\securityapps_master_m\testcases\test_san_tool.py", line 37 in test_TC02_Dictionary
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 170 in pytest_pyfunc_call
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 86 in <lambda>
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 92 in _hookexec
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1423 in runtest
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 125 in pytest_runtest_call
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 86 in <lambda>
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 92 in _hookexec
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 201 in <lambda>
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 229 in from_call
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 201 in call_runtest_hook
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 176 in call_and_report
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 95 in runtestprotocol
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 80 in pytest_runtest_protocol
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 86 in <lambda>
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 92 in _hookexec
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 258 in pytest_runtestloop
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
>   File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 86 in <lambda>
> ```
>
> File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 92 in
>   _hookexec
>         File "c:\python37_32\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in **call**

Comment: I don't see how it's connected with pywinauto. It looks like an issue in `pluggy` package. Don't know what it is. Can you try the same code without pytest?

Comment: Thanks Vasily Ryabov, As per your suggestion i can figure out the problem and solved it. its related to pytest, pluggy and pytest-html version issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. my python version was,

> $ python --version
> Python 3.7.2

and my pytest was

pytest==5.3.5.
I got the exact the same problem you got.

I downgraded the pytest to 4.0.0 and it worked perfectly fine.

On another machine with a python version of 3.7.0 and  pytest==5.3.5, i did not notice the problem.

Therefore, either downgrading the python from 3.7.2 to 3.7.0 or downgrading the pytest to a lower version will work.I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Addishiwot Shimels, you saved my day:-)

Comment: my pleasure! can you kindly mark the answer as "solved"?

Comment: Downgrading pytest to pre-5 didn't work for me. Context: pytest with pytest-qt. But in fact I'm getting the idea that the problem is in a error-ridden 'Doze DLL. See this thread: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7634.